# the stack and vtable [re]location

Tags: c++, assembly, g++, x86-64, inline-assembly

**NOTE:** To understand my question, you *might* need to know about my project and the problem.  If not,  skip right to the "QUESTION" section at the bottom.

---

**PROJECT**
I'm working on a writing a C++ class that enables its parent to act like synchronous/blocking threads by having Pause() and Resume().

Here's an example of how it would work.

```
class BlockingThread
   : public BlockingThreadBase // all the Asm magic happens in BlockingThreadBase
{
  void StartStopHere(void) // called upon the first Resume() call (pure virtual in base)
  {
    printf("1"); Pause();
    printf("3"); Pause();
    printf("5"); Pause();
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  BlockingThread obj;

  obj.Resume(); printf("2");
  obj.Resume(); printf("4");
  obj.Resume(); printf("6");

  return 0;
}

// OUTPUT: 123456
```

I've tried true threading and several novel ideas but they ended up too slow to transfer between code locations **21 million times per second.**

My latest idea is use chunks of the stack (stack buffers) to create the illusion of multiple stacks.  When obj1.Resume() is called, it would return to location of its personal stack, `New #1 Stack`, execute until Pause() and then return to the previous stack location it was at.

---

**ILLUSTRATIONS**

How the stack would look without any`BlockingThread` objects in main().

```
 _________________
| Normal | Stack  |
| Stack  | Buffer |
|________|________|
```

How a`BlockingThread` object in main() would look like on the stack.

```
 ___________________________________
| Normal | Stack  | New #1 | Stack  |
| Stack  | Buffer | Stack  | Buffer |
|________|________|________|________|
```

How **two**`BlockingThread` objects in main() would look like on the stack.

```
 _____________________________________________________
| Normal | Stack  | New #1 | Stack  | New #2 | Stack  |
| Stack  | Buffer | Stack  | Buffer | Stack  | Buffer |
|________|________|________|________|________|________|
```

---

**PROBLEM**

When moving to a "new" stack, and then calling obj.Resume() (from main) which in turn call StartStopHere() causes a segfault at the point of calling StartStopHere().  GDB says `can't find linker symbol for virtual table for 'BlockingThreadBase' value` when I try to get the value of a member variable from BlockingThreadBase.  This is why I suspect it has the same problem when trying to find the location of StartStopHere() when it's called.

---

**QUESTION**

(ignore the italics words if you didn't read the other sections)

How can I find [*and move or copy*] the vtable (or its location if that's what's stored) of the class in the [*normal*] stack [*to a new stack*]?

Comment: how is the BlockingThreadBase implemented?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for Coroutines? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutines

Comment: also very interesting but still not an answer to my question.

Comment: Gravis, So you have no pointers to objects on the stack and want to find any  object on the stack by byte-by-byte scanning tha stack?? It is not very easy task to find a objects here

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for [fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_%28computer_science%29)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is cooperative threading. For a fast and simple implementation of it, check out libco. http://byuu.org/files/libco_v16.tar.bz2. The coswitching is implemented in raw assembly and works for x86, x86_64, PPC32 and PPC64. It also has implementation (ab)using setjmp/longjmp and posix ucontext (very slow).
The overhead with this kind of stack swizzling is about 5x. 20 million swaps / sec should work fine. There are some test programs included to test speed.

Example:

```
#include "libco.h"
#include <stdio.h>

static cothread_t t1;
static cothread_t t2;

static void foo(void)
{
   for (int i = 1; i < 10; i+=2)
   {
      printf("%d\n", i);
      co_switch(t1); // Swap back to main cothread
   }
}

int main(void)
{
   // Get a handle to the current coinstance.
   t1 = co_active();

   t2 = co_create(10000, foo); // New cothread with stacksize 10000.

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i+=2)
   {
      printf("%d\n", i);
      co_switch(t2); // Swap to cothread t2.
   }

   co_delete(t2);
}
```

Comment: Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /files/libco_v16.tar.bz2 on this server.

Comment: While interesting, it does not answer my question and it has some limitations like needing to know what thread it will change to.  I'm also going to be targeting ARM next, so it's best I know what is actually happening.  Getting this information may also help me in the future, so I really want to know. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that magic of your project is happening via some assembly magic. This obviously implies that this will be architecture-specific. To check how to access vtable (or vpointer) to class from assembly, best would be simply to check how copiler does it when accessing virtual method - simply disassble your code and see. 
On x86 linux g++ copiled program i tested - first four bytes of object are pointer to a table (allocated statically i think) of virtual functions.

I don't think there is any method of doing it architecture independent, as different architectures might use different approaches to vtables. Therefore i wouldn't expect c++ to have any means for it.

So much about your question. I think however, that if simple memcpy(&BlockingThread, sizeof(BlockingThread)) does not work, then there is not much more you will be able to copy.